# Using The AudioToolbox Framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audiotoolbox

I am new to sound in XCode, I am using sound effects. I want a sound effect and I know that for sound effects you should use audio toolbox framework, what is the code? How do I code it, what are the variables and properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert the sound to lei16 caf. [Here's a good write up](http://www.raywenderlich.com/204/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-file-and-data-formats) that explains why you should use that format.

```
afconvert -d LEI16 -f caff /path/to/mp3-or-wav-or-whatever
```

Here's the code to play it.

```
// I usually store "mySound" in an instance variable in the view
// controller init
CFURLRef mySoundUrl = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("my_sound"), CFSTR("caf"), NULL);
SystemSoundID mySound;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(mySoundUrl, &mySound);
CFRelease(mySoundUrl);

// Plays the sound.
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
```

Comment: I would also suggest using AVFoundation for longer sounds.  Although it is slightly less efficient, AVFoundation allows you to play sounds in a larger variety of formats with longer durations.